# Lightning Record Edit Form saving issue

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform

I have an issue with my Aura Component, where when users save the Component I am getting an email with the error printed in it. The error is:

Action failed: lightning:recordEditForm$controller$submit [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getUnqualifiedList')]

getUnqualifiedList does not exist in my code so I am confused as to where it is coming from?

Comment: Can you please add minimal required code?